# What is the difference between "creative writing" and "fiction writing"?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

My college offers many writing courses. I notice, one course is called "Creative Writing" and another is called "Fiction Writing". What is the difference between creative writing and fiction writing?

Comment: creative doesn't always mean fictitious. One can be quite creative in science for instance and write a more creative non-rigorous paper. Perhaps that is one of the core differences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In terms of what *your college* is offering and the differences, your best bet is to *ask them directly*.

In terms of the wider world of writing, based on my own experiences in my own locale:

- **creative** writing should focus on the *art* and *style* of writing,
- **fiction** writing on the *technical* and *functional*.

So in creative writing you'd learn to *experiment, have fun, and grow* as a writer, while in fiction writing you'd learn how to be *a professional author*.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Zayne's answer, Creative might cover poetry, essays, or non-fiction, while Fiction is specifically fictional narratives (short stories or novels).